# If $\gcd(x,y)=1379,\operatorname{lcm}(x,y)=n!$ then find $n$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

If $\gcd(x,y)=1379,\operatorname{lcm}(x,y)=n! $ then find $n$  ($x,y,n$ are positive integers).
I tried using the relation: $\gcd(x,y)\cdot\operatorname{lcm}(x,y)=xy$ and also wrote $1379=7\cdot197$ but nothing more.

Comment: Since $197$ is prime you need $n\ge197$. Can  you see how to choose $x,y$ so that $n=197$ works?

Comment: @almagest Why is it necessary that: $n>=197$?

Comment: Because none of $1,2,\dots,n$ can be divisible by a prime greater than $n$.

Comment: @almagest  you mean this equation $7*197*n!=xy$  implies $n>=197$??!! I think it's not necessary that $n$ be divisible by $197$,on the other hand $x$ or $y$ should be...

Comment: The gcd is divisible by 197, so the lcm is divisible by 197, so $n!$ is divisible by 197. Since 197 is prime that means that at least one of $1,2,\dots,n$ is divisible by 197. That means that $n\ge197$.

Comment: @almagest Thank you so much for your clear explanation,that really solved my problem.

Answer (score 3):

Since $\gcd(x,y)=7\cdot 197$, we can assume $x=7\cdot 197a$, and $y=7\cdot 197b$, where $\gcd(a,b)=1$. Then $\text{lcm}(x,y)=7\cdot 197\cdot ab=n!$. Thus, $n\geqslant 197$. Actually, we can assign different prime factors of $\frac{n!}{7\cdot 197}$ to $a$ and $b$ respectively to make sure they are coprime.

Answer (score -1):

$n$ can be any integer which is no smaller than $197$.